# Compare multiple columns: If identical value 1 otherwise 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare, case

I have a large dataset of firm pairs with their funding venture capitalist and I want to check whether only one partner of the pairs is funded by a VC (if yes column OVC=1, otherwise 0), both partners are funded by at least one VC (if yes column BVB=1) or whether both partners are funded by the same VC (if yes column CVC=1). At the moment my table has the columns Partner11 with its funding VCs VC11 to VC17 and Partner22 with its funding VCs in VC21 to VC27. In order to be able to illustrate the headers in one line, I left out VC14-VC17 and VC24-27 in the table below.

```
Partner11 | VC11 | VC12 | VC13 | Partner22 | VC21 | VC22 | VC23 | OVB | BVB | CVC

FirmA     |      |      |      | FirmB     |      |      |      |  0  |  0  |  0
FirmC     | Moa  |      |      | FirmD     |      |      |      |  1  |  0  |  0 
FirmE     | Moa  | Fred | Bob  | FirmF     |      |      |      |  1  |  0  |  0
FirmG     |      |      |      | FirmH     |  Bob | Zoe  | Jet  |  1  |  0  |  0 
FirmE     | Moa  |      |      | FirmF     |  Jet |      |      |  0  |  1  |  0
FirmG     | Moa  | Fred | Bob  | FirmH     |  Jet | Zoe  |      |  0  |  1  |  0 
FirmG     | Moa  | Fred | Bob  | FirmH     |  Bob | Zoe  | Jet  |  0  |  0  |  1
FirmG     | Jet  | Bob  | Fred | FirmH     |  Bob | Zoe  | Jet  |  0  |  0  |  1
```

If no partner is venture-backed, OVB, BVB and CVC take the value 0 (see row 1).

To insert 0 or 1 in the OVB column, the code should check whether one partner of the pair has at least one value in the columns VC11-VC17 for partner11 or (excl.) in the columns VC21-VC27 for partner22 (see row 2 to 4).

To insert 0 or 1 in the BVB column, the code should should check whether both partners have a value at least in one of their VC columns (for partner11 in VC11-VC17, for partner22 in VC21-VC27) (see row 5+6).

To insert 0 or 1 in the CVC column, the code should compare the values of the partners' VC columns with each other, that means VC11 should be compared with VC21, VC22, VC23, VC24, VC25, VC26 and VC27; VC12 with VC21, VC22, VC23, VC24, VC25, VC26, VC27 and so on (see row 7+8).

I would really appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Holy unnormalized table Batman!

Comment: I programmed it before with IF statements in Excel but then my data table became far too large and I had to switch to SQL. Thus the table probably is so unnormalized. Sorry!

Comment: You do need to normalize your data structure - unless there's some (not yet evident) reason why VC11 and VC12 are different. If you've got values that should be comparable, then they ought to be in the *same* column (in separate rows)

Comment: yep - i would agree... stop right now and get your table structure right.  this will save you headaches from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is the nastiest query I have ever wrote.  But, when your table is that un-normalized, this is what you end up with.  Let me know if this helps in anyway:

Run the following to update `OVB` and `BVB` and `CVC` ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ac26/16/0)):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET OVB = 
CASE(
  CASE(
    (CASE Datalength(VC11) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC12) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC13) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC14) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC15) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC16) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC17) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
  ) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
  +
  CASE(
    (CASE Datalength(VC21) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC22) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC23) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC24) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC25) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC26) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC27) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
  ) WHEN  0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
, BVB = 
CASE(
  CASE(
    (CASE Datalength(VC11) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC12) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC13) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC14) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC15) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC16) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC17) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
  ) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
  +
  CASE(
    (CASE Datalength(VC21) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC22) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC23) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC24) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC25) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC26) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
    (CASE Datalength(VC27) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
  ) WHEN  0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
, CVC = 
CASE WHEN   
  CASE WHEN
    (CASE Datalength(VC11) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
    (CASE WHEN VC11 = VC21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC11 = VC22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC11 = VC23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC11 = VC24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC11 = VC25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC11 = VC26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC11 = VC27 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END) >= 1
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  +
  CASE WHEN
    (CASE Datalength(VC12) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
    (CASE WHEN VC12 = VC21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC12 = VC22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC12 = VC23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC12 = VC24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC12 = VC25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC12 = VC26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC12 = VC27 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END) >= 1
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  +
  CASE WHEN
    (CASE Datalength(VC13) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
    (CASE WHEN VC13 = VC21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC13 = VC22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC13 = VC23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC13 = VC24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC13 = VC25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC13 = VC26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC13 = VC27 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END) >= 1
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  +
  CASE WHEN
    (CASE Datalength(VC14) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
    (CASE WHEN VC14 = VC21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC14 = VC22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC14 = VC23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC14 = VC24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC14 = VC25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC14 = VC26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC14 = VC27 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END) >= 1
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  +
  CASE WHEN
    (CASE Datalength(VC15) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
    (CASE WHEN VC15 = VC21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC15 = VC22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC15 = VC23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC15 = VC24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC15 = VC25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC15 = VC26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC15 = VC27 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END) >= 1
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  +
  CASE WHEN
    (CASE Datalength(VC16) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
    (CASE WHEN VC16 = VC21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC16 = VC22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC16 = VC23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC16 = VC24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC16 = VC25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC16 = VC26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC16 = VC27 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END) >= 1
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  +
  CASE WHEN
    (CASE Datalength(VC17) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
    (CASE WHEN VC17 = VC21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC17 = VC22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC17 = VC23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC17 = VC24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC17 = VC25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC17 = VC26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    (CASE WHEN VC17 = VC27 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END) >= 1
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END >= 1
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, linger. Unfortunately, when running your code the error message "An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Add a name or single space as the alias name." comes up for lines 4 onwards, even though the columns OVB, BVB, CVC exist as smallint null. The first "<>" in line is marked as wrong syntax. What can be the reason for these errors?

Comment: I modified my answer.  Try to run each update query separately and see if any of them work.

Comment: For all of the queries the error "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'" pops up. The other error message beginning with "An object column name..." comes up as well for line 4 onwards.

Comment: I updated the first query to use the CASE expression.  Try it out and let me know if it works for you.  If it does then I can convert the other two update statements.

Comment: It seems that there is problem with the ,"" in the line 5ff. The SQL server recognizes the table and all columns but underlines the ,"" in red again with the error message "An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO ..."

Comment: I made a modification to the query that updates `OVB`.  try it and see if it works.

Comment: Now the usual error message is not appearing anymore. Only the brackets  at the end of each line (from line 5 onwoards) seem to cause trouble since the error message "Incorrect syntax near to ')'" is popping up.

Comment: I updated the first query and made sure it worked.  Before i was just going of the top of my head.  I also added a SQL Fiddle link to demonstrate.

Comment: **@user2713440**, I finished modifying the query.  It is now one query that updates all three fields.  I also linked the SQL Fiddle to demonstrate that it indeed works.  it is a very nasty looking query due to the table not being normalized.